# Python Requests-HTML - Can't find specific data

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I am trying to scrape a web page using python requests-html library.
link to that web page is https://www.koyfin.com/charts/g/USADebt2GDP?view=table ,
below image shows (red rounded data) the data what i want to get.

[image]

My code is like this,

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.koyfin.com/charts/g/USADebt2GDP?view=table')
r.html.render(timeout=60)
print(r.text)
```

web page html like this,

[image]

Problem is when i scrape the web page i can't find the data i want, in HTML code i can see
the data inside first div tags in body section.
Any specific suggestions for how to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the data is being loaded by JavaScript code after the initial page load. One solution is to use `Selenium` to drive a web browser to scrape the page. But using a regular browser I looked at the network requests that were being made and it appears that the data you seek is being loaded with the following AJAX call:

```
https://api.koyfin.com/api/v2/commands/g/g.gec/USADebt2GDP?dateFrom=2010-08-20&dateTo=2020-09-05&period=yearly
```

So:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.koyfin.com/api/v2/commands/g/g.gec/USADebt2GDP?dateFrom=2010-08-20&dateTo=2020-09-05&period=yearly')
results = response.json();
print(results)
for t in results['graph']['data']:
    print(t)
```

Prints:

```
{'ticker': 'USADebt2GDP', 'companyName': 'United States Gross Federal Debt to GDP', 'startDate': '1940-12-31T00:00:00.000Z', 'endDate': '2019-12-31T00:00:00.000Z', 'unit': 'percent', 'graph': {'column_names': ['Date', 'Volume'], 'data': [['2010-12-31', 91.4], ['2011-12-31', 96], ['2012-12-31', 100.1], ['2013-12-31', 101.2], ['2014-12-31', 103.2], ['2015-12-31', 100.8], ['2016-12-31', 105.8], ['2017-12-31', 105.4], ['2018-12-31', 106.1], ['2019-12-31', 106.9]]}, 'withoutLiveData': True}
['2010-12-31', 91.4]
['2011-12-31', 96]
['2012-12-31', 100.1]
['2013-12-31', 101.2]
['2014-12-31', 103.2]
['2015-12-31', 100.8]
['2016-12-31', 105.8]
['2017-12-31', 105.4]
['2018-12-31', 106.1]
['2019-12-31', 106.9]
```

**How I Came Up with the URL**

[image]

And when you click on the last message:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay Booboo, I have some questions. I don't know any thing about AJAX, so i wonder how or where did you create or get that AJAX call ? How did you know parameters names?

Comment: In my browser, Chrome, I right-mouse clicked and selected "Inspect" from the context menu. Then I selected "Network" from the Inspection menu. Then I selected "XHR" to show me XMLHttpRequest calls (so-called "AJAX" asynchronous Java and XML calls).

Comment: If the answer is helpful, don't forget to "ACCEPT' the answer.

Comment: Wow that's cool. with JSON it's very useful. Thanks friend